# Get list of values based on Checkbox value type

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I am having items names with checkbox and I want to show the list of values based on the checkbox value type.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pb-1" *ngFor="let item of Typename">
          <mat-checkbox>{{item.type}}</mat-checkbox>
       </div>
      <div class="pb-2" *ngFor="let product of allprod">
        {{produc.name}}
      </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
this.testservice.getall().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.allprod = data;
        console.log('submit Post click happend' + JSON.stringify(this.allprod));
     });
}
```

I want to show the values based on the selected checkbox value type

Answer (score 0):

You could put in a filter in your finder method like this :

```js
const type = checkboxType;
this.testservice.getall()
.pipe(
   filter((e) => e.type === checkboxType)
)
.subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.allprod = data;
        console.log('submit Post click happend' + JSON.stringify(this.allprod));
     });
}
```

is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Based on the checkbox value we want to show the type value

Comment: the filter will do that - it will only show the values matching the checkbox value

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="pb-1" *ngFor="let item of Typename">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked">{{item.type}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<div class="pb-2" *ngFor="let product of filtered">
  {{produc.name}}
</div>
```

```
get filtered() {
    return (this.allprod || []).filter(p => this.Typename.filter(t => t.checked).map(t => t.type).includes(p.type));
}
```

Each item's `checked` property is binded to the `checkbox`.
We will filter the `allprod` which the type of product is included in the selected types.

Comment: Function calls in template expressions are considered bad practice and should be avoided. Read further https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496

Comment: Getting error Property 'checked' does not exist on type

Answer (score 0):

Please consider grouping your data beforehand. (example with lodash)

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash';

this.testservice.getall().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  this.allprod = groupBy(data, 'type');
  // this.allprod is now an object with type values as key and arrays as values
});
```

And then in template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of Typename">
  <div class="pb-1">
    <mat-checkbox>{{item.type}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="pb-2" *ngFor="let product of allprod[item.type]">
    {{product.name}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```